# In netty, how to share data between downstream and upstream handlers

Tags: netty

I am writing asynchronous client in netty. I need information about request message type sent to server to be able to decode the response came back from the server. In other words, decoding logic needs information about request message type. How can I get hold of this information in upstream handlers or decoders?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Channel.setAttachment(..), Channel.getAttachment()

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But due to asynchronous messaging, I am not sure if this approach would work. Say for example, I send request messages type A and type B one after another to server and save them in attachment with Channel.setAttachment(). But it is not guaranteed that I get response to request type A before I send request type B. In that case when I get response to request type A, the attachment in channel could be of type B, which of course is not what I wanted. I am new to netty and may not be understanding it clearly. Appreciate some details on it.

Comment: I think for thisyou would need to handle the mapping in a Map.